# Couldn't move component in Experience manager at SDL WEB 8

Tags: experience-manager, web8

After install the DXA package, we can edit the DXA example site. At its home page, I want to move the company news section to the middle and let the latest news section at right side.

The Move button is enabled, so do the move up button. But when we drag the component and drop it in the middle of Latest news area and head office area, nothing change at UI. It still display at the right side.

Any idea why?

Best regards,

Qiang

Comment: Moving items on a Page can be restricted by XPM regions, so it makes sense that you edit your question and provide a bit more detail on the problem.

Comment: I just updated the text and changed the example, which is based on the default DXA site home page, with no other change.